# Developing interactive charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

Here is my requirement.

I have to develop a Dashboard kind of website. So i searched a lot for Javascript libraries which supports AJAX , Json and also for interactive charts. I got some but unable get output.

I have database, where i need to fetch the data and transform this data to json format and call this json object using ajax. The whole application must be written in asp.net web application.

So any one please please suggest best suitable Javascript library that meets all the above requirements. It would much helpful if any one provide some examples or complete code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use charts.js www.chartjs.org/‎
or highcharts www.highcharts.com

Comment: hi shashank, thank for the reply. I tried using Chart.js, but not able to connect to database and make it database driven charts. Also i dint get any such examples to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is multiple options.

I like to use the following third party javascript plugins.

[* Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). Very easy to use. very well documented. most of their plugins are free.

[* Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/)

[* Charts.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) <- HTML5 based. very nice look

By using Highcharts you could load data asyncronus using ajax. This is an example of how to:

```
function requestData() {
   $.ajax({
       url: 'URL_TO_YOUR_JSON_WEBSERVICE,
       type: "GET",
       dataType: "json",
       data : {username : "demo"},
       success: function(data) {
          chart.addSeries({
            data: data.month_mentions_graphic
          });
      }
   });
)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. But neither of them given any example for how to use json object which is generated from database. :-(

Comment: You can't directly couple a javascript library to a database. You have to develop some kind of middle ware. I have included an example of how to get data from e.g. a web service using highcharts and ajax.

Comment: Im using Highcharts my self for an interactive realtime dashboard in our IT department

Comment: Hi JuniorCoder, Is HightCharts requires any client side installation ??

Comment: No it needs no installation on any clients. It is installed serverside

Comment: JuniorCoder.. Thanks alot.... Now am able to meet all of my requirements using HighCharts. Thanks alot....

Answer (score 0):

It seems the [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) library is interactive and useful for your case. it also use json for generating charts and have multiple types of charts. try it.

Comment: Mojtaba.. Thanks alot.... Now am able to meet all of my requirements using HighCharts. Thanks alot....

Answer (score 0):

Try **D3JS** it has **inbuilt json functions**(Even csv and tsv formats)

http://d3js.org/

This is the tutorial for the **JSON data inputting** and converting it into a chart..
Take a look at his other videos for the rest of the tutorials.

Some examples if you wanna take a look..

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for advanced interactive javsacript charts, I would suggest having a look at

[ZoomCharts.com](https://zoomcharts.com/en/)

benefit of those charts is the extent to which you can control everything in them. Also they are touch-device oriented, so that you can take advantage of new devices around.

[image]